# Why does an ngSanitize dependency break my app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, ngsanitize

*To whom it may concern*,

In effort to bind some html, which, to note, will include angular directives, upon injecting an ngSanitize dependency, my app ceases to render. Any thoughts as to why this happens, and whether my code has any blatant issues?

TLDR: everything works fine until bring ngSanitize into the picture!

**Working Controller**:

```
angular.module('appName')
 .controller('DecksCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $http) {. . .
```

**Broken Controller**:

```
angular.module('appName', ['ngSanitize'])
 .controller('DecksCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $http) {. . .
```

**Console Errors**:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module appName due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider
```

*Thank you*

Peter Ward

Comment: you don't have `ui.router` as dependency and errror being thrown on $stateProvider

Comment: ajmajmajma what does that mean, `loaded`?

Comment: I do have ui-router as a depency. bower and npm installed that

Comment: but it's not in module dependency shown...is it injected in another module?

Comment: charlietfl, viz. http://i.imgur.com/MqQbM0Z.jpg

Comment: just because it's loading the file on page using bower doesn't mean it is set as a dependency of your angular app modules

Comment: I installed and saved ui-router to a bower.json file via Yeoman angular-fullstack generator

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491276/error-module-when-inject-ui-router

Comment: I don't know how or why sanatize would cause an injection error with `$stateProvider`. Are you sure you have all your dependancies correctly injected in the right spots?

Comment: OK...I see the problem...you injected ngSanitize in a module `reference`...not in a module `declaration`. Find the main module declaration and it's dependency array and inject it there

Comment: charlietfl, okay, I will try to find the "main module" and I will get back to you, okay?

Comment: @PeterWard gave you answer with path in your project, unless that generator has changed in the last few months. good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is misunderstanding the difference between a module `declaration` and a `reference` to an existing module.

To declare a module there are 2 arguments, the name and the dependency array

```
angular.module('appName', [/* all the dependencies for this module*/]);
```

Then when you add components you use the module reference getter that does not have second dependency argument. This getter returns the module object for chaining the component(s) to

```
angular.module('appName')
 .controller('DecksCtrl', function ($scope, Auth, $http) {. . .
```

What you have done is try to inject a dependency into a module reference getter. this in turn over wrote the original declaration for that module

Comment: Yes, you are right, my problem was that basic misunderstanding. Thanks for helping me work through it, and, happy to say: I have since found the declaration and put ngSanitize there. Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 0):

You want to inject it in your `app.js` .  In that yeoman generator its - appName / client / app / app.js

```
angular.module('yourapp', [
  //your injections here
 'ngSanitize',
 'other injection',
 'another injection'

]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {
```

You declare all of your apps dependancies here.

Comment: can inject into any module in the app. Last statement about individual module is not right

Comment: Why shouldn't be just inject directly into the controller? In an app with multiple controllers, would'n that be modular?

Comment: @Mawg with what version of angular are you asking this question? This answer was provided for about 1.4~

Comment: I am seeking to understand 1.x  (1.5, actually), where I am currently having a problem injecting sanitize and $sce directly into one of my two controllers

Comment: @Mawg it’s been a while, but I believe you have to inject all your main dependencies into the app like that, then you inject them into the controllers you are using them in.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks. Is it time to switch to Angular 4? Have things like UI-bootstrap been converted?

Comment: @Mawg Depends on what you are working on my friend. If you have a greenfield project I would use angular 4 - personal opinion of course. If you are working on a legacy project maybe stay with what you have. I think there is still a angular 1.x bootstrap directives, but you can also find plugins for new versions of angular. good luck!

Comment: Thanks for that (+1). Existing projects will, of course, be finished with 1.x, but I think that it is about time to move up. As to bootstrap, I am also wondering whetheer to switch to CSS grid, but can't think of a S.E site where the question would be allowed